# Spring boot @ConditionalOnBean does not detect bean missing, throws exception "No qualifying bean of type"

Tags: dependency-injection, spring-boot, conditional-statements

Have this @Configuration class that requires a bean implementing JmsProperties which is declared in the @ConditionalOnBean

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnBean(JmsProperties.class)
public class JmsConfiguration {

    @Inject
    private JmsProperties properties;
    ...
}
```

Getting exception:

```
   Caused by: 
   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:        
   No qualifying bean of type [com.....JmsProperties] found for dependency:
```

Isn't the @ConditionalOnBean supposed to detect this missing bean and not try to inject the dependency in the first place?

Thanks in advance for any pointers

Comment: JmsProperties is a custom class, not from Spring, which is initialized through TypeSafe config. the intention here is to only initialize the JmsConfiguration if JmsProperties bean is present, which @ConditionalOnBean should be able to detect, as far as I understand. but still JmsConfiguration is initialized without JmsProperties and hence the exception

Comment: Replace `@Inject` with `@Autowired(required=false)` that should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

You've cross-posted on the [Spring Boot tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4104) and the developers responded:

> `@ConditionalOnBean` is evaluated after all configuration classes have been processed, i.e you can't use it to make a whole configuration class conditional on the presence of another bean. You can, however, use it where you have to make all of the configuration's beans conditional on the presence of another bean.

Comment: I added Andy Wilkinson's reply to make your answer not link-only.

Answer (score 0):

You must use @ComponentScan(basePackages="".
Without using it your app wont discover & register/instantiate all defined beans and hence you would end up with this type of exception i.e. No bean def found.